# jquery refresh div when content changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have index.php and images.php. And what I want is that a certain div on index.php is getting it's content from images.php automatically and refresh when new content is present on images.php. I currently have this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
setInterval(function() {
    $('#images').load('images.php');
}, 500);
});
```

This works fine, but it refreshes the div every .5s which I don't want, I want it to detect when new content has been inserted into images.php then load it in.

But the thing is, on images.php I have some timestamps (1 minute ago, etc.). And jQuery will detect those as changes and will then refresh.

Is there a way to count the number of image tags (`<img>`) on the images.php page and compare them with the number of image tags in the div on the index.php page, and then if they are not equal, refresh the div on index.php.

Comment: You could have images.php return json array which would contain the image elements.  `<?php echo json_encode($your php array containing the img tags);`  This way you can count the number of tags in the array.

Also, `$('#images').children()` will return an array containing the img tags and `$('#images').children().length` will give you number of tags in it.

Comment: yes probably there is a way of "counting" the image tags, you could probably try to make your life easier if you used a "JSON" object than XML. `if(object.length!=$(selector img).length){do_change};` but using a small timestamp and  playing with the timestamp of the last change of the image list would be somekind more *efficient* than just loading each time.

Comment: How do I send the image paths and timestamps from PHP to JavaScript?
And how can I have two arrays sent and how do I differentiate the two in JS?
Currently in PHP I have an array that stores the image paths and another which contains raw timestamps, how would I go about sending them? Do I need two separate pages?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is - no.

You should understand, that there's server side of your code and client side. Whenever browser sends a request, it gets a formatted html page (not a php script to execute) and gets all embedded resources (images, css, js files etc).

After that no communication is done between the client (browser) and a server (your web server). For you to get updated 'images.php' page you'd need to send a notification from a server to all browsers looking at your page currently (which you don't know - you'd need a fixed connection with them, but html protocol is **stateless** meaning there's no easy way of accomplishing it).

So, the easiest way is to have browser ping server in a timely fashion - every n seconds. Though, it would probably be better to fetch not all images every n seconds, but the last change date - and have some logic to fetch new data when it has a newer change date - this would reduce amount of traffic sent by your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
var imageWrapper = $('#images'),
    imageCount = $imageWrapper.find('img').length;

setInterval(function() {
    $.get('images.php', function (html) {
        html = $(html);
        if ( html.find('img').length > imageCount ) {
            $imageWrapper.html( html );
        }
    });
}, 500);
```